# Deciding 2d vector size automatically from csv file

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I have a C++ code to load 2d vector from csv file. Here, output.csv file has a data of 65 x 74496. In this code, I fixed the size of row and column to 65 and 74496. However, in the future, the number of row and column could be changed depending on data. Do you know a method to select the number of row and column from csv file automatically. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const std::string csvFileName{ "output.csv" };
constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 65U; // I want to decide this number from csv file automatically
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 74496U; // I want to decide this number from csv file automatically

int main() {
    // writeTestFile();

    // Our data
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data(NumberOfRows, std::vector<std::string>(NumberOfColumns));

    // Open file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream testFileStream{ csvFileName }){//; testFileStream) {

        size_t row{};
        std::string line{};
        line.resize(1'000'000U);

        // Read all lines/rows in a loop
        while (testFileStream >> line) {

            size_t columnIndex{};
            std::vector<std::string> columns(NumberOfColumns);

            // split strings
            std::istringstream iss{ line };
            for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); columns[columnIndex++] = std::move(part))
                ;
            // Add all column values
            data[row++] = std::move(columns);
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open file: " << csvFileName << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::cout << data[1][1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do not need to pre-allocate memory, make representation of your `csv line` let's call it `Data`, read line by line and make `Data` from each line, add data to `std::vector<Data>`

Comment: Number of lines = Rows, Number of values in one line = Columns

Comment: `line.resize(1'000'000U);` will be undone by `testFileStream >> line`. It might hold on to the million bytes allocated, but otherwise oodles of wasted time. Perhaps [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) will be a better fit.

Comment: `testFileStream >> line` won't read the whole line unless the line is a single whitespace-delimited token. You probably want `getline` here as well as when parsing commas.

Comment: Note: [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) solves the problem you're asking about. Start with them and then test to see if the results are fast enough before playing around with prealliocating. Preallocating reduces the number of memory allocations, but requires you to read the file twice. The repeated file IO is probably more expensive than the `vector` resizes.

Comment: Please write the answer for the purpose.

Comment: Gentlemen. This question is a copy and paste from my answer yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567974/it-is-too-slow-loading-2d-vector-from-csv-file/65568537#65568537. Unfortunately not a complete copy and paste. And, you need to understand the context. There is no whitespace. Push_back was intentionally removed. Of course, reserve or resize is necessary. And no, the extractor operator will not change the size of the string.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567974/it-is-too-slow-loading-2d-vector-from-csv-file/65568537#65568537)

And here is the modified version that use dynamic array sizes.

With the sam source file of 46MB, It takes 1399ms.

ANd as written several times: Please enable C++ 17 in your compiler!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const std::string csvFileName{ "r:\\test.csv" };
constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 65U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 74496U;


void writeTestFile() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ofstream testFileStream{ csvFileName }; testFileStream) {

        // Write all columns
        for (size_t row{}; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {

            //  Special handling for separator. No comma at the end
            bool writeCommaFirst{ false };

            // For all columns
            for (size_t col{}; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {

                // // Create some test string
                std::string temp = "R" + std::to_string(row) + "C" + std::to_string(col);

                // Write data
                testFileStream << (writeCommaFirst ? "," : "") << temp;
                writeCommaFirst = true;
            }
            testFileStream << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError. Could not write file" << csvFileName << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    // writeTestFile();

    // Our data
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data{};

    // Open file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream testFileStream{ csvFileName }; testFileStream) {

        std::string line{};
        line.reserve(1'000'000U);

        // Read all lines/rows in a loop
        while (std::getline(testFileStream, line)) {


            size_t columnIndex{};
            std::vector<std::string> columns{};

            // split strings
            std::istringstream iss{ line };
            for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); columns.emplace_back(std::move(part)))
                ;
            // Add all column values
            data.emplace_back(std::move(columns));
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open file: " << csvFileName << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Armin, thanks for your help. Can we get NumberOfRows and NumberOfColumns from csv file?

Comment: I edited the code. It is now full dynamic. There can be as many rows and columns as you wish. Even different numbers of columns in different rows are possible. The number rows is, after reading, data.size() and the number of columns, for example for row 0 is data[0].size();

Comment: Armin Montigny, thanks it works very well! You are so smart!

Comment: Hi Armin Montigny, I made a 2 d vector, vector<vector<double> > EEG_data; I want to copy data (results of reading csv file) to EEG_data as double. for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            EEG_data[i][j] = (double)data[i][j];
        }
    }

Comment: This code does not work. EEG_data[i][j] = (double)data[i][j]    Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: The result of loading csv file is data[i][j], but it is not double type. I think I need double type to start calculation. Is it possible to change it to double type?

Comment: I cannot change the type of data to double. It is my problem.